After creating jenkins in aks cluster I cannot able to access to the external IP address
I have created AKS cluster and i have installed all required things into it and created jenkins in that aks cluster,
After creaking jenkins i have got external IP adress and my pods was running without any error but when i able to access the external IP its showing site can't be reached i had tried by chaning the YAML fies but i didn't get any solution
i had tried by chaning the YAML fies but i didn't get any solution,  i was expecting to acess url and access to the jenkins...

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

If you're having trouble accessing Jenkins via the external IP address after setting it up in AKS, there could be several factors at play. You should ensure that the service type is set to LoadBalancer in your Jenkins deployment YAML file, which will expose Jenkins to an external IP. After that, verify if the load balancer has been successfully created and has an external IP listed. If the external IP address is in a pending state, you might need to wait for the cloud provider to provision it.

if all good, then you'll be able to access your Jenkins dashboard.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: jenkins
  ports:
  - name: test1
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080


Below are some default checks you can do to verify your setup
Ensure that there are no network policies in place that restrict access to the Jenkins service.
kubectl get networkpolicy -n default

If you're running AKS in a cloud environment (like Azure), check the network security group (NSG) rules to ensure that incoming traffic on port 8080 is allowed. In my case there is no firewall and kept inbound to all (*) and (any)
also, cross check if you can temporarily use port forwarding to access your Jenkins server directly via localhost.
kubectl port-forward svc/jenkins-service 8080:8080 -n default


Reference:

Jenkins setup using helm
Jenkins setup using yaml

